# Unexpected scroll to top on a web page rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, html

Some webpages made out of a mixture of HTML, Javascript/jQuery have a strange behaviour, that is if the user scrolls down while the page is loading and rendering at the same time, view may be scrolled back to top of page unexpectedly, once the page rendering has completed

Apart from explicit commands, are there any other possible reasons regarding page design that could lead to this beahviour?

Here's a page with this beahviour: http://www.staging1.acornhouse.school/academics/subjects/art/

Comment: Ya but would be easier to debug if you provide any online link...

Comment: javascript ,autofocus, hashes, a lot can happen

Comment: I have added a link in the original request

Comment: I had a look at their js code and I found something like `ajaxScrollToOffset:"0"` which scrolls the page back to top. 
Reason for scrolling back to the top could be - They want highlight a few things, want you to have a look at those.

Comment: Did you fin this in Javascript code? If so, what is the offending script?

Comment: @Riccardo Yes. If you inspect the code, you will find this on line 782 in index.html. I suspect scrolling is happening due to this.

Comment: Apparently `ajaxScrollToOffset:"0"` is a parameter for the essential grid, however another page has the same object (a grid) with the same parameter, but scroll to top is not occurring see here http://www.staging1.acornhouse.school/academics/subjects/technology/

Comment: @Riccardo It's happening on that page as well. Go to page end while page is loading. Once the loading is complete, you are sent back to the top.

Comment: See if this occurs here http://www.staging1.acornhouse.school/school-life/extra-curricular-activities/dsa-tutoring/

Comment: Occurs over here too and there's no grid: http://www.staging1.acornhouse.school/contact/

Comment: Are there some steps I can follow to debug javascript from start to end (requires stepping into each script!)

Comment: @Riccardo Checked twice but didn't happen for staging1.acornhouse.school/contact

Comment: Yes if you want to observe each and every step.

Comment: Can I achieve this with Chrome inspect? BTW I am bounced at top of page in the contacts page, I wonder why this will not occur on your browser...

Comment: Yes you can. Not sure why it didn't happen on your end. I am using Chrome latest version

Comment: Last question! Is there a way in Chrome debugger to hook all javascript scroll events somehow? and THANKS for helping!!!!

Comment: You are welcome. You can attach event handlers from console.